# How to write unit test case for JWT secured RestController in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, spring-restcontroller

I am writing a unit test case for one of my Rest Controller.

```
@WebMvcTest(AppAdminUserController.class)
public class AppAdminUserControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private AppAdminUserService appAdminUserService;



    @Test
    public void testGetAllAdminUsers() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(appAdminUserService.getAll()).thenReturn(List.of(AppUsers.users()));
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/users").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());

    }

}
```

RestController looks like this:

```
@RestController
@Api(value = "Application Admin User operations", description = "Operations pertaining to Admin Users")
public class AppAdminUserController {

    @Autowired
    private AppAdminUserService appAdminUserService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    @ApiOperation(value = "View list of all existing admin users")
    public List<AppAdminUserDto> getAllAdminUsers(){
        return appAdminUserService.getAll();
    }
}
```

Spring security with ldap is enable in the application, So actual flow is user first call an endpoint `/login` with credentials and get a JWT token. This JWT token is used in subsequent requests including "/users".

**JWTWebSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class JWTWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter;

    /*@Autowired
    private Environment env;*/

    @Value("${jwt.get.token.uri}")
    private String authenticationPath;

    @Value("${ldap.domain}")
    private String ldapDomain;

    @Value("${ldap.url}")
    private String ldapUrl;

    @Value("${ldap.base}")
    private String ldapBase;

    @Value("${ldap.search_query}")
    private String ldapSearchQuery;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider =
                new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(ldapDomain, ldapUrl,ldapBase);

        authenticationProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        authenticationProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        authenticationProvider.setSearchFilter(ldapSearchQuery);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/swagger-ui/**",
                        "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()  //H2 Console Needs this setting
                .cacheControl(); //disable caching
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
        webSecurity
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        authenticationPath
                )
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .and()
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/" //Other Stuff You want to Ignore
                )
                .and()
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**");//Should not be in Production!
    }
}
```

**JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint**

```
@Component
public class JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8970718410437077606L;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                "You would need to provide the Jwt Token to Access This resource");
    }
}
```

When I am trying to run my test case, I am getting below error

```
Description:

Field jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint in com.org.app.config.JWTWebSecurityConfig required a bean of type 'com.org.app.jwt.JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.org.app.jwt.JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint' in your configuration.
```

As per my understanding I am getting this error as my endpoint in actually secured by JWT validation but Not sure how can I write test for that and why Spring not able to find the bean ?

Regards